# Why does a variable not need a type inside a static block

Tags: java

A programming like this,

```
static {
  a = 6;
}
```

Why the element "a" does not need a **type**?

Comment: 'a' does need a type. The type of a must be declared above the static block or else it will fail to compile.

Comment: This itself won't compile.

Comment: [This](http://www.jusfortechies.com/java/core-java/static-blocks.php) is the best reference I found on this topic.

Answer (score 10):

This is not a declaration of a variable, this is the assignment of a variable. The type of 'a' is defined somewhere else. So, this code itself won't compile, you'll need a variable declaration like:

```
class X {
     private static int a;

     static {
         a = 6;
     }
}
```

As an answer to the comment below, this is the initializion sequence:

1. Static statements/static blocks are executed.
2. Instance variables are assigned default values
3. Instance variables are initialized  if the instance variable is assigned a compile time constant. Otherwise, it will be done with Item 5 (instance variables *and* instance initializers will be done together from the top to the bottom, in the order they are defined).
4. constructor runs
5. Instance initialization block(s) run after all the call(s) to super has(have) been completed but before the rest of the constructor is executed.
6. Rest of the constructor is executed.

Comment: Does that static run before constructor?

Comment: Checkout Chapter 12.4 for an answer for that: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html

Comment: I've updated my example with a more extended answer [source](http://www.coderanch.com/t/267125/java-programmer-SCJP/certification/Initializing-Sequence)

Answer (score 1):

Every variable needs a type in Java.

Answer (score 0):

I think somewhere you initialized the variable  a

```
 private static int a;
static {
  a = 6;
  }
```